# MVC: how to pass an array and variable from a model to a view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass the `$task` array and the `$str_pag` variable to the view. I try to declare the variable `$str_pag` as public but the view displays an array, and the variable does not.

**Controller**

```
class Index extends Controller{
   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     require 'views/header.php';
     require 'models/index_model.php';

     }

   public function index() {
     $tasks = Index_Model::index($id, $login, $email, $password);
     require 'views/index/index.php';
     require 'views/footer.php';
     }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Index_Model extends Model
{
    
    public $str_pag;
    
    public function index($id, $login, $email, $password)
    {
        $db = new Database();

        if (isset($_GET['page'])){
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }else 
            $page = 1;

        $total = Index_Model::getCount();
        $kol = 3;  
        $art = ($page * $kol) - $kol; 

        $str_pag = ceil($total / $kol);

        $stm = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ?,?');
        $stm->bindValue(1, $art, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->bindValue(2, $kol, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->execute();

        $task = array();
        $i=0;
        while($row=$stm->fetch()) {
            $task[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $task[$i]['email'] = $row['email'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $task;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a specific Framework?

Comment: _Small Point_ If you only want the columns `name` and `email` then select only `SELECT name,email....`

Comment: @Riggs, No, this is simple MVC

Comment: So show us the controller where you are trying to pass values to a view

Comment: You can't send values between the model and the view. Only the controller sends data to the view. Like said RiggsFolly, show us your controller

Comment: @RiggsFolly, controller I add, but i don't now how send value

Comment: So now I think we need to see the View code

Comment: Your controller has to return a view, like smarty or twig. What is the template engine you use?

Comment: @Skyd, controller I add, but i don't now how send value

Comment: Sure, but what is the template engine you use ? Twig ? Smarty ? Blade ? If you don't have one, check Twig and install it : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/intro.html and add the code in your controller and voila

Comment: Mate, I think you write code in plain php? If so, there is no sending value. You define variable as any else like $a = 5; and then, after, in required files (view) you use it. So, in controller define value by calling a function defined in model which will return value you need. Once you have that value/variable in controller require your view bellow and then call that var in view with the same name as you defined it in controller like <?php echo $a; ?>. That's all.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, in the view goes first the cycle `foreach ($tasks as $task) {...` , and after the `echo $str_pag`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return from Model anything you need as an array of values.

Then, inside your Controller where you call your Model methods just assign it to the variables that will be passed to the view.

Solution:

In Model change `return $task;` with `return [$task, $str_pag];`

Then in Controller edit your `index()` method like this:

```php
public function index() {
     list($tasks,$str_pag) = Index_Model::index($id, $login, $email, $password);
     require 'views/index/index.php';
     require 'views/footer.php';
}
```

Just to mention, trying to access Model's public property from the View is not a good idea, because it's break the whole `MVC` idea. The same thing about accessing global variables like `$_GET` from your Model code. Instead of this - pass it as parameter and get it from `return` statement.

That's Controller responsobility to "Control" all that stuff.